# Codenameone: Sharing a file leads to an empty target-app-selection-Dialog

Tags: codenameone

I try to share a file (zip or text - I tested both) from within my codenameone App using the share-API. But on my iOS-Devices (iPhone and iPad with iOS 13.3.1) the result is, that the Dialog, where an App can be selected with which you want to share the file, is empty (see Screenshot).

I used this call for the text file:

```
Display.getInstance().share(null, "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0999760A-D194-450D-8E27-B0D5D852FB93/Documents/de.zeitkuenstlervoll.gtd.gui/mylog.txt", "text/plain");
```

and this for the zip-file:

```
 Display.getInstance().share(null, "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0999760A-D194-450D-8E27-B0D5D852FB93/Documents/de.zeitkuenstlervoll.gtd.gui/export.zip", "application/octet-stream");
```

The files are written with FileSystemStorage and always exists in the path (creating an Email with the mentioned files as attachments from within the code works well). Sharing a Text with the share-API works well (selection-dialog is not empty).

Do you have any idea what I can do to share text-files oder zips?

[image: Screenshot empty target-selection-dialog]

Comment: This could be a regression with the newer iOS version. Please file an issue with a reproducible test case and the OS version.

Comment: I filed issue https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3050